# perform a raw query on Android's call log db

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, calllog

I would like to perform a raw query on Android's call log db (android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI).

*in my case, i'd like to perform a "sum" query with "group by"

I've read a lot of posts with about doing this with

```
getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI , ...)
```

but that does not seem to work (at least, from what I read, since Android ICS)

Can this be done? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Note that there is no requirement that the call log be implemented via a SQL database.

Comment: I understand... though it makes sense that it would imo. any alternatives in mind? (other than creating my own db based on info from the content resolver)

Comment: "any alternatives in mind?" -- run a query for the rows you want, and do the sum/group-by logic in Java in your app.

Comment: Thanks, but I also thought of that. I want to do this query a lot of times, so that option is not very efficient for my purposes

Comment: You are welcome to make a fork of Android that exposes additional capabilities for you to query the call log. Or, you can get rid of the feature from your app that requires this query. Or, you can get rid of the app entirely. Or, you can live with the inefficiency from the only stable solution, which is doing the sum/group-by logic in your app.

Comment: Loved the "getting rid of the app" idea. I'll even consider changing professions :) thanks for the suggestions. inefficiency it is.

Comment: Sorry -- the `ContentProvider` facade is intentionally limited to allow some measure of implementation flexibility, but it does pose problems. Fortunately, most standard OS providers do not really need much in the way of aggregate functions, `GROUP BY`, and so forth. The `CallLog` is probably the most likely one for it. You wind up treating a `ContentProvider` much like you would a REST Web service that you didn't design. Whatever the API supports you can use; anything else that you could do with access to the Web service's databases is unavailable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaborate answer!